# How to append query param with all the links added with ckeditor5-react?

Tags: ckeditor5-react

I am using [ckeditor5-react](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-react) text editor. I just want to append the query param with each link added inside editor. Is there any way to do this using ckeditor5?